# strpos always returning true

Tags: php, mysql

My code always return "true" whatever the string is I tried a bunch of thing but they are only return false... I have no idea what I can do to fix this... my code:

```
public function isBlacklisted($string)
{
    $apis = mysql_connect("mysql.hostinger.fr", "mysql user", "testpass") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("u770656121_api", $apis);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM blacklist";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $apis);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $username = $row['username'];
        if (strpos($string,$username) !== 0) {
            return true;
            break;
        } else {
            return false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `var_dump($string, $username)`? That said, you are checking strictly for `int(0)` not `bool(false)`. `strpos` returns `bool(false)` if nothing was found. `0 == false` but `0 !== false`.

Comment: Are you trying to test for a non-match, or a match at position zero in the string? Most typically, you would need to test `strpos($string,$username) !== FALSE` because `0 !== FALSE` and strpos returns 0 when the match occurs at the start.

Comment: `if (strpos($string,$username) !== 0) {return true;...}`

If the username is not the at the beginning of the string, return true. Is that what you meant to code?

Comment: tl;dr; Read the documentation before asking a question: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strpos` returns `false` is it is not found, and `0` if it is in the first position of the string.  It sounds like you want to do:

```
if (strpos($string,$username) !== false) {
```

Also, you are looping over the DB results, you should only return if it is found:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $username = $row['username'];
    if (strpos($string,$username) !== false) {
        return true;
    }
 }
 return false;
```

Or, even better:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blacklist WHERE 'username' LIKE '%$username%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $apis);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   if ($row['username']) return true;
}
```

making sure to escape `$username` and ideally switching to `mysqli` or `pdo` instead of using deprecated `mysql` statements.